# ArrayAdapter.getItem java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: android

I created an Android application. I've an Activity where the user type the country name and an autocomplete shows a list of countries.
The list is get via an HTTP REST request.

This is a screenshot of the autocomplete:

[image]

It works fine, but sometimes (usally when I type just 2 chars) I got this exception and from the stacktrace I can't figure out where the problem come from:

```
2019-11-13 22:13:02.556 18726-18726/it.test.mobile E/it.test.mobil: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-11-13 22:13:02.627 18726-18726/it.test.mobile E/it.test.mobil: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-11-13 22:13:02.768 18726-18726/it.test.mobile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: it.test.mobile, PID: 18726
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:393)
        at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.buildImeCompletions(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1243)
        at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1203)
        at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1086)
        at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1068)
        at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class CountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
    public Resources res;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String TAG = "CountryAdapter";

    /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public CountryAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Country> objects, Resources resLocal) {
        super(activity, textViewResourceId, objects);
        try {
            activity = activity;
            if (objects != null)
                countryList = objects;
            res = resLocal;
            /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () **********************/
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logcat.e(TAG, "Errore: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logcat.e(TAG, "Errore: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (countryList != null)
            return countryList.size();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    // This funtion called for each row ( Called data.size() times )
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            /********** Inflate spinner_rows.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_country, parent, false);

            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/


            return row;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logcat.e(TAG, "Errore: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the code that updates the adapter:

```
public class GetCountry extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, JSONObject> {

private AutoCompleteTextView autocomplete;

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
    try {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(AddFinesActivity.this);
        String url = UtilityFunctions.getBaseUrl(AddFinesActivity.this) + Globle.GET_COUNTRY + params[0];
        autocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) params[1];
        Logcat.d(TAG, "doInBackground: url :" + url);

        json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url, JSONParser.GET, UtilityFunctions.getToken(AddFinesActivity.this), UtilityFunctions.getLanguage());
        return json;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logcat.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject result) {
    if (result != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = result.getJSONObject("_embedded");
            countryArray = object.getJSONArray("countries");
            //reset the list
            countryArrayList.clear();
            if (countryArray != null && countryArray.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < countryArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = countryArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    countryArrayList.add(Country.getCountryFromJson(c));
                }
            }


            mCountryAdapter = new CountryAdapter(AddFinesActivity.this, R.layout.layout_item_country, countryArrayList, getResources()) {
                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView mTextViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
                    TextView mTextCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_code);
                    ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_country);

                    if (countryArrayList != null && countryArrayList.size() > 0) {
                        mTextViewName.setText("" + countryArrayList.get(position).getName());
                        mTextCode.setText("" + "(" + countryArrayList.get(position).getAlpha2Code() + ")");
                        try {
                            mImageView.setImageDrawable(FlagKit.drawableWithFlag(getContext(), countryArrayList.get(position).getAlpha2Code().toLowerCase()));
                        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                            //if the flag is not found is not a problem
                        }
                    }

                    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {


                            if (autocomplete.equals(mEditTextCountry)) {
                                contactCountryLink = countryArrayList.get(position).getLink().getSelf();
                                contactCountryName = countryArrayList.get(position).getName();
                                setContactCountryName(position);
                            } else if (autocomplete.equals(mEditTextLicensePlateCountry)) {
                                licensePlateCountryLink = countryArrayList.get(position).getLink().getSelf();
                                licensePlateCountryName = countryArrayList.get(position).getName();
                                setLicensePlateCountryName(position);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return view;
                }
            };
            if (mCountryAdapter != null) {
                mEditTextCountry.setAdapter(mCountryAdapter);
                mEditTextLicensePlateCountry.setAdapter(mCountryAdapter);
                mCountryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logcat.e(TAG, "Errore: " + e.toString());
        }
    }


}
```

}

I was looking for line 393 in `ArrayAdapter.java` but I don't see it. 
Any hints to understand the point where the exception is raised?

==== SOLUTION ======

Finally I solved, following this tutorial: https://ridwanolalere.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/how-to-implement-auto-complete-in-android-with-remote-server-data/

I hope it can helps

Comment: Is one of the links in the stacktrace blue? that'll be the one you want to select for the IDE to focus on the problem code. Either way, somewhere you are trying to reference an array index [1] when the size is only 1 (meaning the only reference point in the array/list/arraylist is [0])

Comment: crash when typing or after clicking?

Comment: @PavelPoley when typing. Expecially when I type very fast

Comment: @StitchesS Thanks, my bad. My IDE was not refreshing source code and I didn't see the entire code but just the decompiled bytecode.

Comment: can you post the code that updates the adapter

Comment: @PavelPoley Done

Comment: does this combination of chars you type exist in the country list?

Comment: @PavelPoley It does. I'm typing "it"

Answer (score 1):

It hard to understand and need to debug, but i think it `GetCountry` may called multiple times, you have same reference to `countryArrayList` from `GetCountry` and `adapter`, that mean that `countryArrayList` may cleared and initialized while the adapter is rendering the views and the position of the view can be > from `countryArrayList` size.
So maybe try to isolated `countryList` in adaper instead asigning use `countryList.clear()` and `countryList.addAll(objects)` in `adapter` constructor.